# Difference Recycleview: set color in CreateView or BindView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm learning android and don't know much of it but obviously saving resources is important so I was wondering if one practice of setting a background color significantly outperforms the other:

for me it makes sense to set a background color on the view in "onCreateViewHolder", like so:

```
@Override
public WordsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout,parent,false);
    **inflatedView.setBackgroundResource(colorID);**
    return new WordsHolder(inflatedView);
}
```

Rather than setting it on each row in the "onBindViewHolder", but as I understand it android will only set the color once on each object contained in the view and since they are recycled that might only be like e.g 10 rows(or is it reset every time a view is recycled?).

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WordsHolder holder, int position) {
    Words word = mWordList.get(position);
    //STUFF
    **holder.row.setBackgroundResource(colorID);**
}
```

Both of these options works well but which one "should" I use?

Comment: If its goings to always be the same color regardless of view holder content you can set it wherever you want. But if you want the color to change based on the content of the view holder you will need set it in onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Devsil says, `onCreateViewHolder()` is for things that are common (e.g. if your color is constant, should be set there) and `onBindViewHolder()` for things that are different from row to row.

The reason is to avoid setting a value (or finding a `View`, or creating something) all over and over again. `onCreateViewHolder()` is only called to create an item, later `onBindViewHolder()` is called to set the specific values. But when later the item is recycled (reused) it doesn't need to be recreated, and only `onBindViewHolder()` is called, avoiding as much expensive operations as possible.

Comment: As I suspected then, this answers my question and hopefully anyone else who are learning about recycling views, cheers!

Comment: Glad it helped!